# troubles with nokogiri gem on mountain lion using bundler

Tags: ruby, rubygems, bundler, nokogiri

I can *SUCCESSFULLY* install nokigiri using

```
sudo gem install nokogiri -- --with-xml2-include=/usr/local/Cellar/libxml2/2.9.1/include/libxml2  --with-xml2-lib=/usr/local/Cellar/libxml2/2.9.1/lib --with-xslt-dir=/usr/local/Cellar/libxslt/1.1.28 --with-iconv-include=/usr/local/Cellar/libiconv/1.14/include --with-iconv-lib=/usr/local/Cellar/libiconv/1.14/lib
```

however when I run "bundle install" I have libxml2 problems.  My question is:  how do I get nokogiri to install via bundler?

here is my "bundle install" output:

```
Installing nokogiri (1.6.0) 
Gem::Installer::ExtensionBuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    /Users/philswenson/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p448/bin/ruby extconf.rb --with-xml2-include=/usr/local/Cellar/libxml2/2.9.1/include/libxml2
Extracting libxml2-2.8.0.tar.gz into tmp/i686-apple-darwin11/ports/libxml2/2.8.0... OK
Running 'configure' for libxml2 2.8.0... OK
Running 'compile' for libxml2 2.8.0... OK
Running 'install' for libxml2 2.8.0... OK
Activating libxml2 2.8.0 (from /Users/philswenson/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448@3rdrevolution/gems/nokogiri-1.6.0/ports/i686-apple-darwin11/libxml2/2.8.0)...
Extracting libxslt-1.1.26.tar.gz into tmp/i686-apple-darwin11/ports/libxslt/1.1.26... OK
Running 'configure' for libxslt 1.1.26... OK
Running 'compile' for libxslt 1.1.26... OK
Running 'install' for libxslt 1.1.26... OK
Activating libxslt 1.1.26 (from /Users/philswenson/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448@3rdrevolution/gems/nokogiri-1.6.0/ports/i686-apple-darwin11/libxslt/1.1.26)...
checking for libxml/parser.h... yes
checking for libxslt/xslt.h... yes
checking for libexslt/exslt.h... yes
checking for iconv_open() in iconv.h... yes
checking for xmlParseDoc() in -lxml2... no
-----
libxml2 is missing.  please visit http://nokogiri.org/tutorials/installing_nokogiri.html for help with installing dependencies.
-----
*** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of
necessary libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more
details.  You may need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
    --with-opt-dir
    --with-opt-include
    --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
    --with-opt-lib
    --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
    --with-make-prog
    --without-make-prog
    --srcdir=.
    --curdir
    --ruby=/Users/philswenson/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p448/bin/ruby
    --with-zlib-dir
    --without-zlib-dir
    --with-zlib-include
    --without-zlib-include=${zlib-dir}/include
    --with-zlib-lib
    --without-zlib-lib=${zlib-dir}/lib
    --with-iconv-dir
    --without-iconv-dir
    --with-iconv-include
    --without-iconv-include=${iconv-dir}/include
    --with-iconv-lib
    --without-iconv-lib=${iconv-dir}/lib
    --with-xml2-dir
    --without-xml2-dir
    --with-xml2-include=${xml2-dir}/include
    --with-xml2-lib
    --without-xml2-lib=${xml2-dir}/lib
    --with-xslt-dir
    --without-xslt-dir
    --with-xslt-include
    --without-xslt-include=${xslt-dir}/include
    --with-xslt-lib
    --without-xslt-lib=${xslt-dir}/lib
    --with-libxslt-config
    --without-libxslt-config
    --with-pkg-config
    --without-pkg-config
    --with-libxml-2.0-config
    --without-libxml-2.0-config
    --with-libiconv-config
    --without-libiconv-config
    --with-xml2lib
    --without-xml2lib


Gem files will remain installed in /Users/philswenson/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448@3rdrevolution/gems/nokogiri-1.6.0 for inspection.
Results logged to /Users/philswenson/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448@3rdrevolution/gems/nokogiri-1.6.0/ext/nokogiri/gem_make.out

An error occurred while installing nokogiri (1.6.0), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install nokogiri -v '1.6.0'` succeeds before bundling.
```

Could someone point me in the right direction?

Thanks!

Comment: `libxml2 is missing` So you need to install it

Comment: You should not be using sudo with a local-user install of RVM. Did you install nokogiri 1.6.0 with the first command?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't be using `sudo` if you're using RVM or similar Ruby versions manager.

Comment: turned out that removing "sudo" on the initial nokogiri install solved the problem.  So run the "gem install nokogiri (with params)" first.  Then run "bundle install" after and bundler works fine.  It does seem like I should be able to tell bundler where the libs are though, but I was unsuccessful with passing params to bundler.

Comment: sudo rvm installs gems to root's gem path, not the current user IIRC.  It also might use another ruby, like the system framework one.

Answer (score 0):

This works on the latest Xcode CLT, mountain lion and mavericks, and nokogiri 1.6.1

## Interim solution 0

exactly nokogiri's patches as brew formulas libxslt and libxml2

```
curl -L https://gist.githubusercontent.com/steakknife/8969368/raw/install_nokogiri_brew_osx.sh | bash
```

[if you dont trust https pipe to shell, here's the script raw url](https://gist.githubusercontent.com/steakknife/8969368/raw/install_nokogiri_brew_osx.sh). [[gist url]](https://gist.github.com/8969368)

Way faster and gives a known good, keg-only copy of libiconv and nokogiri's libxml2 and libxslt.  System libxml2 isn't touched.

## Interim solution 1

This takes a couple minutes and eats up 100 MiB+ when installed.

```
gem install nokogiri
```

Either way, libxml2 needs to become more stable or it's a de-facto fork and more work for everyone.

Don't bother link-ing libxml2 or libxslt, sudo anything, or make install libiconv either, these are unnecessary and fragile.